# Class Veins::VeinsInetManager not found

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet, veins

I've installed veins_inet project with omnet++ 5.0 and sumo 0.28. When I try to run the .ini on veins_example file this error appears:

> Error in the module(omnetp::cModule) Scenario during network setup: Class Veins::VeinsInetManager not found

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the whole error message?

This kind of error can happen when the project is not properly created. To check that, verify if there is a folder named "Includes" in your project (you can see it in eclipse). If no, create a new project in Eclipse `New` | `Project` | `OMNeT++`, and paste your files there.